# c++ linkedlist list operator[]

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying to implement linkedlist, and i have some problem with operator[]

```
template <class T>
T& L1List<T>::at(int i){
    L1Item<T> * pRet = this->_pHead;
    int idx = 0;
    while(pRet){
        if(i != idx){
            pRet = pRet->pNext;
            idx++;
        }else  return (pRet->data);
    }
}


template <class T>
T& L1List<T>::operator[](int i){
    return at(i);
}
```

and when i compile it, it runs with list->at(i), but list[i].
int a = list[i]; the error is that "cannot convert L1List'<'int> to ‘int’ in initialization"

Answer (score 5):

If `list->at(i)` works, it means that `list` is a pointer, not an object. Hence, `list[i]` evaluates to an object. That's why `int a = list[i];` does not work, which also explains the error message. You cannot use a `L1List<int>` to initialize an object of type `int`.

You need to use:

```
int a = (*list)[i];
```

or make it really complicated and use:

```
int a = list->operator[](i);
```

Comment: thank you, btw is there a way that i just use list[i]?

Comment: @HuyNguyễn, you can use `list[i]` if you change `list` to be of type `L1List<int>` instead of a pointer to `L1List<int>`.